# Computer not booting after removing graphics card?

Tags: debian, graphics-card, motherboard, post, proxmox

A recent machine was given to me use as a ProxMox (basically Debian) server. It uses an Asus H310M-K motherboard and it came with an Nvidia Geforce 710 graphics card. It booted already just fine, even without an OS on it.

In trying to install ProxMox, I saw that the UI would freeze in the middle of the installation and so I decided to scrap the graphics card. The only problem is that now it won't even boot to the BIOS screen. I hear 1 long beep and 3 short beeps, which [seem to indicate a graphics problem](https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm). However, I reset the CMOS (and verified by seeing that the date and time were reset), removed and put back the RAM, and all that, but the machine still won't boot to the BIOS screen and so I'm stuck.

Am I missing something dumb?

Comment: You don't indicate if the process has a iGPU or not.  You should edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so thanks to the comment of @Ramhound, I realized that I am missing something dumb. The processor is an [Intel Core i3-9100F](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/190886/intel-core-i3-9100f-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html) and [according to this site](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/intel-core-i3-9100f-s-1151-coffee-lake-refresh-quad-core-4-thread-36ghz-42ghz-turbo-6mb-w-o-igpu-65w#:%7E:text=The%20Intel%20Core%20i3%2D9100F,to%20output%20to%20a%20display):

> The Intel Core i3-9100F processor DOES NOT feature an iGPU.

Thus, my problem is logical and I just took it for granted that the CPU had an integrated GPU.